# How to implement back referencing in python?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am trying to implement a logic where you can back reference objects. I think an example would make it clear.

```py
class State:
    def __init__(self, name, allowed_transitions=None):
        self.name = name
        self.allowed_transitions = allowed_transitions or []

run = State('Run')
walk = State('Walk', allowed_transitions=[run, 'Sprint'])
sprint = State('Sprint', allowed_transitions=[walk])
```

In above code, `run` can be referenced in `walk` state as an object but `sprint` can not be since it is defined after `walk` state.

I want to allow support of two types `State` and `str`. I could convert or transform a name given as a string to a State object inside the State constructor but does not seem elegant solution.

Similar things is supported in Django framework where you could back reference 
the model class name using string. I want to achieve similar functionality.

```py
author = ForeignKey('Person')
```

What is the best way to handle this use-case ?

Comment: Is it possible to do `walk.allowed_transitions.append([sprint])` after you create `sprint`?

Comment: allowed_transitions are only set during the construction of the state so no to answer your question.

Comment: You could then make factory function that returns an constructed object and shields user from complicated object creations.

Comment: First define all the `State` objects with no transitions, then add the `allowed_transitions` to each one.

Comment: @martineau It depends on intended usage. I have a similar use-case (sort of circuit simulator with blocks and interconnections) and personally find it very convenient to use names instead of variables. First, variables are against DRY (e.g. `walk = State('walk'); run = state('run')`). Second, it helps to focus on the circuit when it is possible to build it in one pass. However my solution is plain and boring, not elegant, I will not post an answer here.

Comment: Make a dictionary mapping state names to state objects (which could be automated to a large degree). _Always_ store state name strings in `allowed_transitions`. State names can be used to look up the associated `State` instance in the dictionary whenever it's needed. Alternatively, you _could_ make `State('walk')` automatically create a global variable named `walk`...and even though that's generally considered a bad practice, I think it might be OK in this situation.